# JGAP IntegerGene returning null on calling getAllele() method

Tags: java, jgap

I am using JGAP library for my GA..

I am creating the chromosome like this

```
Gene[] genes[i] = new IntegerGene(conf,someInteger, someInteger);
Chromosome mChromosome = new Chromosome(conf, genes);
conf.setSampleChromosome(mChromosome);
```

But when I try to retrieve the Gene Values of the chromosome. I get null

```
Gene[] genes = chromosome.getGenes();
int value = (Integer)genes[someIndex].getAllele();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

`IntegerGene` is created after evolving the population

If I tried to access the chromosome after the evolution like this

```
Gentype population = Genotype.randomInitialGenotype(conf);
population.evolove();
Ichromosome chromosome = population.getFittestChromosome();
Gene[] genes = chromosome.getGenes();
int value = (Integer)genes[someIndex].getAllele();
```

It will work